# cassandra datadog dashboard monitoring

Tags: performance, cassandra, database-performance, datadog, nosql

Is there any default dashboard to monitor Cassandra performance in data dog?

https://app.datadoghq.com/account/settings#integrations/cassandra

There are lot of metrics listed. How do we construct a monitor? By default the data dog shows the default system level monitor like CPU, Heap etc... is there anything like it for Cassandra? Any info would be a great help for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Datadog blog should guide you on how to build a monitor.

https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/monitoring-cassandra-with-datadog/

Answer (score 4):

There is indeed a [template Cassandra dashboard](https://app.datadoghq.com/dash/integration/cassandra) in Datadog (where I work) that should appear as soon as you enable the integration. This dash has a mix of Cassandra-specific metrics (e.g. cache hit rates), plus metrics from the host (e.g. CPU). You can select a particular host or subset of hosts to make those host-level metrics more meaningful by [changing the scope of the dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqO7Z.png), and the graphs will re-render on the fly. You can also clone and modify the dashboard as you wish by clicking the gear icon in the upper right.

This dash should provide a good starting point for monitoring Cassandra, but we have an even better template dashboard in the works. I'll update this answer as soon as it's released. In the meantime, the blog post shared by John KVS should help you to identify key metrics that you might want to monitor.